# AIR FileStream larger than 10GB

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing a program that must load very large files, larger than 10GB

AIR has no problem opening it, reading bytes, etc.

However, it seems I can't really process it past the 10GB point or so by setting the FileStream.position property... any idea why?

Is there any way to read/process bytes from a file of arbitrary size (as long as OS supports it) in AIR?

Comment: Is breaking it down into smaller parts an option?

Comment: This is a pretty crazy problem (I'm very curious what kind of files you're processing with so much data).  I think as Marty suggests dealing with it in chunks might be a better option... if all else fails there is always Adobe Native Extensions (ANE).  Due to the bulk size of the data you may even get a significant performance boost by using native extensions.

Comment: Just fyi, 2^53 bytes = 9 petabytes, so that's probably not the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonatan - corrected

Comment: shaun - large video files. Will look into Native Extensions...

Comment: @davidkomer: 9 petabytes is 9x10^6 gigabytes (9000000 GB). I don't think that's the limit you are reaching ;) Maybe you are simply running out of ram (and swap?) when using the data?

Comment: Hey @JonatanHedborg - right, that's why I corrected it to say I'm not sure what the error is :) Though, changing the position pointer shouldn't affect any ram/swap, and it's not an "OUT OF MEMORY" error I'm getting

Comment: Nevermind.... I separated this test into a unit test and setting position to the end of the file and reading a byte works fine... something else is going on, will need to investigate further